# ClassNotLoadedException when setRoot() of JTree

Tags: java, debugging, jtree

I have a `ClassNotLoadedException` when I try to set `treeModel.setRoot(treeNode)` the root of a JTree.

My code:

```
public static DefaultMutableTreeNode parse(JTree tree, JScrollPane scrollPane, TreeCellRenderer renderer, mySAXParser SAXParser, String newXML) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode;
    mySAXParser parser = SAXParser;
    treeNode = parser.getTreeNode();
    tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    treeModel.setRoot(treeNode);
    TreeSelectionModel treeSelectionModel = tree.getSelectionModel();
    treeSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

    tree.setSelectionModel(treeSelectionModel);
    scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
    expandTree(tree);

    return treeNode;
}
```

Initialization:

```
myTree = new JTree();
((DefaultTreeModel) myTree.getModel()).setRoot(null);
scrollPane= new JScrollPane(myTree);
```

The complete exception message:

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

I don't understand why this is, can anyone help me to understand?